# Can I use "using" without assigning a variable?

Tags: typescript

**TL;DR:**

Is there anything like `using functionWithDisposal()` instead of having to call `using myVar = functionWithDisposal()`?

**Extended version:**

I'm using `using` and `Symbol.dispose` for tracing:

```
export function getSpan(name: string) {
    const span = getTracer().startSpan(name);
    return {
        span,
        [Symbol.dispose]: () => {
            span.end();
        }
    };
}
```

In my function I'm calling `getSpan` like this:

```
function saveData() {
    using span = getSpan('persistingData');

    // I do a lot of things here
}
```

For most of the places I use `getSpan`, I'm not doing anything with what is returned from it. Because of that, `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` error is thrown from my linter. I can of course ignore this rule by just adding `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` but I was wondering if there is a way to use `using` without assigning it to a variable.

What I would like to have:

```
function saveData() {
    using getSpan('persistingData');

    // I do a lot of things here
}
```